# dojo Deferred callback function

Tags: dojo, callback, settimeout, deferred, resolve

I want to write a callback function using dojo Deferred. I wrote two functions, a and b

```
function a() {
        for(var i = 0; i < 3000; i++) {
            ....
        }
    }
```

a need more time, loop is just an example, maybe something else.

```
function b() {
        console.log("b");
    }
```

I hope b can wait for a, that is like a.then(b), i.e. after a is finished, then b begins to run. If i wrote a();b(); 
the result is not what i want, because b is faster than a. Normally I use setTimeout and I do not think it is good. 
For example, a() maybe need 100s, but setTimeout i set 50s, it is not OK??

How can I write use Deferred, can rewrite my functions like a() and b(), that is, one function waits for another one.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

It should be somewhat similar to this:

```
require(["dojo/Deferred", "dojo/dom", "dojo/on", "dojo/domReady!"],
function(Deferred, dom, on){
  function a(msg){
    var deferred = new Deferred();

    setTimeout(function(){
      deferred.resolve(msg);
    }, 1000);

    return deferred.promise;
  }

  function b() {
     console.log("b");
  }

  on(dom.byId("startButton"), "click", function(){
    var a= a("message");

      a.then(function(results){
          console.log("Finished with result:"+results);
          b();
    });
  });

});
```